# Why isn't my full node accepting incoming connections from other nodes?

Tags: full-node

I have a full node on a Gentoo box. I have port forwarding on my router setup so that port 8333 is sent to the IP of my full node. I opened port 8333 on the machine using:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p TCP --dport 8333 -i wlp4s0 -j ACCEPT
```

The node is fully synced with the network and I can watch new blocks arrive in the debug log. I thought I was fully participating in the network, but when I [check for my full node at Bitnodes](https://bitnodes.21.co/) it says that my node is unreachable.

Any suggestions? Is there any other way to test public access to my full node?

Comment: If you run `nc -z localhost 8333; echo $?` does it output 0 (success) or 1 (failure)?

Comment: Freaking Gentoo...had to compile netcat but I do get 0 from that command. I think the problem is somewhere in my router or WiFi configuration.

Comment: Next thing to try is `nc -z <external ip address of router> 8333; echo $?` If that fails, there's a networking issue or a portforwarding issue. PS: Debian rules.